# Consult about FCM settings and managing message priority

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

about setting and managing message priority: https://firebase.google.cn/docs/cloud-messaging/android/message-priority?hl=nb , please ask for some questions, thank you

1. If FCM detects a pattern in which the message does not result in a user-facing notification, your message's priority may be reduced to normal priority.
   Is there a detailed rule description, what kind of message content is in line with the requirements?
2. If the message is reduced to the normal priority, can it continue to use push, and is there any other impact?
3. If the message is reduced to the normal priority, how to restore the high priority?
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYZSR.png)